# R arrays of 3 dimensions with different inner size

Tags: arrays, r, list, element

I have an R list (docs) where its first 2 elements are as follows:

```
1. A. 1 2 5 6
   B. 5 6 2
   C. 7 8 1 2 3 5
2. A. 4 5 3 
   B. 1 2 3 5 4 7 8
```

What I want to achieve is another list with equal sizes but with zeros instead:

```
1. A. 0 0 0 0
   B. 0 0 0 
   C. 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2. A. 0 0 0 
   B. 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have tried:

```
sapply(docs, function(x) rep(0, length(x)))
```

but the behaviour is not the intended because it considers the size of the outer list. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have a list of lists, that is docs is a list containing the lists 1 and 2, which then contain numeric vectors. If this is the case,  try the following:

```
 # create test list
 temp <- list("v1"=list("A"=1:4,"B"=5:7,"C"=1:8), "v2"=list("A"=1:3,"B"=5:10,"C"=3:8))

 # get a list of zeros with the same dimension
 answer <- lapply(temp, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) rep(0, length(y))))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is in the correct direction. Could you propose a way to create list temp (through a loop for instance)? Because in this way it cannot generalize to big matrices of type docs.